# How to create a unique identifier for tracking

Tags: tracking, uniqueidentifier

I'm working on an app that has a **web version, a mobile web version and an ios app**. I need to track the amount of visits, logins, etc. 
For that I need to get every user to have a **tracking unique identifier** that can not be the user_id because **some users are guests**.

The way that we work is that **every link** that we post to bring new users to the app **points to "http://core.APP.com"** and the loaded file **redirects, on the backend** to:

- The app store if the user is using an iPhone and doesn't have the app.
- The ios app if the user is using an iPhone and has the app.
- The mobile web version if the user is using a mobile phone. (m.app.com)
- The web version for the other cases. (www.app.com)

The options I have studied are:

1. **Using the IP as an identifier**. (This is not a good solution because there might be many users with the same ip, and example might be users of corporate networks)
2. **Using cookies**. (We lose track of the users if they log in by opening the iphone app directly)
3. **Using a hash created by calculating the md5 of the string created by concatenating the ip and the http_user_agent.** (This has been the best option we have found because we don't only separate by ip, but we add the http_user_agent which should make the identifier more unique).

Is there any way to make the identifier unique for all users??

NOTE: We are planning on creating an android app in the future. I would appreciate it if the answer was android compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Users will fall in two categories

- Registered
- Unregistered (guests)

Registered users will again fall in two categories

- Logged in
- NotLoggedIn

Assign a user_id to even guest users. Start tracking them and as soon as they identify themselves (registering, logging in, clicking link in email etc) merge the activity data.

Good thing about this solution is - you are reto-actively tracking usage of you web apps and mobile apps even before they register.

Bad thing is your Database will grow large very quickly, and you need to manage the old data smartly.